# MySQL ORDER BY and then group

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT
    `Thread`.`ID` AS `ThreadID`,
    `Post`.`CreatorName` AS `LastPostBy`,
    `Post`.`CreatorUserID` AS `LastPostByID`,
    `Post`.`CreationDate` AS `LastPostDate`
FROM
    `Post`
        INNER JOIN
    `Thread` ON `Post`.`ThreadID` = `Thread`.`ID`
ORDER BY
    `Post`.`CreationDate` DESC
```

Which produces the following result :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User2      |           13 | 2016-03-02 09:38:44|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-01 09:27:24|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-02-14 21:27:06|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Now I want to make the result to be grouped by ThreadID, so I add GROUP BY clauses like this :

```
SELECT
    `Thread`.`ID` AS `ThreadID`,
    `Post`.`CreatorName` AS `LastPostBy`,
    `Post`.`CreatorUserID` AS `LastPostByID`,
    `Post`.`CreationDate` AS `LastPostDate`
FROM
    `Post`
        INNER JOIN
    `Thread` ON `Post`.`ThreadID` = `Thread`.`ID`
GROUP BY
    `Thread`.`ID`
ORDER BY
    `Post`.`CreationDate` DESC
```

And I get the following result :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User2      |           13 | 2016-03-02 09:38:44|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-02-14 21:27:06|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

However, my expected result was the record is grouped with the newest LastPostDate listed like this :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User2      |           13 | 2016-03-02 09:38:44|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-01 09:27:24|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

How to get such result?

What is the name of this problem? So in the future I could search by myself.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT :**

The solution provided by [Yossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5992977/yossi) and [Vipin Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153834/vipin-jain) works for the first problem.

However, when the data is like this :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-02 18:55:19|
|       3 | User2      |           13 | 2016-03-02 09:38:44|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-01 09:27:24|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-02-14 21:27:06|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

The provided solution produces this result :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User2      |           13 | 2016-03-02 18:55:19|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-01 09:27:24|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

It should be like this :

```
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|ThreadID | LastPostBy | LastPostByID | LastPostDate       |
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|       3 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-02 18:55:19|
|       2 | User1      |            1 | 2016-03-01 09:27:24|
+---------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: did you try `ORDER BY` = ASC

Comment: The solution is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Lakshya yes I have, the result is still like the **second result** but reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing MAX() function:

```
SELECT
    `Thread`.`ID` AS `ThreadID`,
    `Post`.`CreatorName` AS `LastPostBy`,
    `Post`.`CreatorUserID` AS `LastPostByID`,
    max(`Post`.`CreationDate`) AS `LastPostDate`
FROM
    `Post`
        INNER JOIN
    `Thread` ON `Post`.`ThreadID` = `Thread`.`ID`
GROUP BY
    `Thread`.`ID`
ORDER BY
    `Post`.`CreationDate` DESC
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT
    `Thread`.`ID` AS `ThreadID`,
    `Post`.`CreatorName` AS `LastPostBy`,
    `Post`.`CreatorUserID` AS `LastPostByID`,
    `Post`.`CreationDate` AS `LastPostDate`
FROM
    `Post`
        INNER JOIN
    `Thread` ON `Post`.`ThreadID` = `Thread`.`ID`
WHERE (`Thread`.`ID`,`Post`.`CreationDate`) in(SELECT `Post`.`ThreadID`,
                                                      MAX(`Post`.`CreationDate`)
                                               FROM `Post`
                                               GROUP BY `Post`.`ThreadID`)
ORDER BY
    `Post`.`CreationDate` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but could you give me the name of this problem?

Comment: There is no name, you just group by the ID, and didn't say which creationdate you want to take(since there is more then one) . I'm not sure how it picks, I think randomly.. Therefore - MAX() will return the maximum between all the choises @rizkynggakool

Comment: @rizkynggakool I've updated the answer,should work now

Comment: No problem @rizkynggakool

Comment: so the `GROUP_BY` should be in the `IN` (this is the first sort?) and then the `WHERE` select the related rows according to the `IN` ? am I right?

Comment: The inner query inside the in selects only ID,MAX(DATE) , then the outer query select only the rows with this match ID,DATE = ID,MAX(DATE) , so no need to group by out there because its already filtering only the max ones @rizkynggakool

Comment: I see that, thank you very much for your explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `max` date of user using `MAX()`

```
SELECT
    `Thread`.`ID` AS `ThreadID`,
    `Post`.`CreatorName` AS `LastPostBy`,
    `Post`.`CreatorUserID` AS `LastPostByID`,
    MAX(`Post`.`CreationDate`) AS `LastPostDate`
FROM
    `Post`
        INNER JOIN
    `Thread` ON `Post`.`ThreadID` = `Thread`.`ID`
GROUP BY
    `Thread`.`ID`
ORDER BY
    `Post`.`CreationDate` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but could you give me the name of this problem?

Comment: there is no any error in your query. you just forget get max date.  by using max function you can get... :)

Comment: to get the latest user who post in the thread, anyway it has been answered by Yossi, but thank you for answering this question :)